# DataGrid not showing decimal Places

Tags: c#, wpf

In the SQLite Database the decimal places are shown correctly, it's datatype is real. The problem is when I create a Datatable, which contains the the values, it only shows "12" instead of "12.99".

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="Transaction_DataGrid_Transaction" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" IsReadOnly="True"
                ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
```

Comment: Please post the XAML you are using.

Comment: What is the data source (Binding?)? Have you checked if the data that you read from the DB is correct?

Comment: Yes the data is correctly read from the datatbase.

Comment: AutoGenerate columns doesn't give you much control. Do you have this problem if you define the columns yourself?